# Issue with R dt:datatable top filter

Tags: r, datatable, dt

this may be a very easy question, still I'm quite stuck and can't seem to find a similar issue asked here in stackoverflow.
I have the following sample dataframe:

```
df2 = data.frame(RTG=c("A+","A+","AA","AA"),CITY=c("A","B","C","D"), stringsAsFactors = T)
```

Then, I create the following datatable:

```
datatable(df2, 
          rownames= T,
          colnames = T,
          filter = c('top'),
          extensions = "Buttons", 
          options = list(scrollX = T
                         , lengthChange = T
                         , paging = T    
                         , autoWidth = F
                         , pageLength = T 
                         , dom = 'Blfrtip'
                         , info = T 
                         , searching = F
          ))
```

If I use the RTG filter and select 'AA', also rows with RTG = 'A+' shows up. This seems to make no sense to me. What am I missing?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting the option `searching = F` you deactivated the searching capabilities completely. If you want to get rid of the search field for the whole table while keeping the column filters just remove the "f" from the `dom` option.

```r
  df2 = data.frame(RTG=c("A+","A+","AB","AA"),CITY=c("A","B","C","D"), stringsAsFactors = T)


DT::datatable(
  df2,
  rownames = T,
  colnames = T,
  filter = list(position = 'top'),
  extensions = "Buttons",
  options = list(
    scrollX = T,
    lengthChange = T,
    paging = T,
    autoWidth = F,
    pageLength = 5,
    dom = 'Blrtip',
    info = TRUE,
    dom = `t`
  ))
```

[image]

Comment: oh wow, I had no idea about that. I indeed thought that search = F was only impacting the search box on the top left. Thank you so much!